# Discord bot replies increasing by 1 each time

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

My bot is increasing its replies by one per command sent. (1 response, then 2 and so on)
What do I do to fix it? There aren't any other instances running, I've changed the token. I need this to stop and I've followed multiple tutorials on an advanced command handler and it is working besides the commands repeating.

main.js code:

```
,client.on('message', message =>{
if (message.author.bot) {
    console.log("Ignoring bot message.");
    return;
}
if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return

const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/)
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase()

const baseFile ='command-base.js'
const commandBase = require(`./commands/${baseFile}`)

const readCommands = dir => {
    const files = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, dir))
    for (const file of files) {
        const stat = fs.lstatSync(path.join(__dirname, dir, file))
        if (stat.isDirectory()) {
            readCommands(path.join(dir, file))
        } else if (file !== baseFile) {
            const option = require(path.join(__dirname, dir, file))
            commandBase(client, option)
        }
            
        }
    }
```

add.js code:

```
    commands: ['add', 'addition'],
    expectedArgs: `<num1> <num2>`,
    permissionError: 'You need admin permissions to run this command.',
    minArgs: 2,
    maxArgs: 2,
    callback: (message, arguments, text) => {
        const num1 = +arguments[0]
        const num2 = +arguments[1]

        message.channel.send(`The sum is ${num1 + num2}`)
        return
    },
    permissions: [],
    requiredRoles: [],
}
```

Comment: Why is there a permission error message, if your permissions array is empty?

Comment: You are adding command to your array every time someone triggers a command. Put the code responsible for adding commands outside of the event handler.